# Apex 4.2.4 conditional LOV

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

[image: LOV]

Trying this conditional query, but getting  an error that it should start from 'select'.
How am I supposed to use conditions?

Comment: I don't see what is wrong with this question. It's valid. Maybe OP is relatively new to apex and believes this is the only way to do this. Vincent answered and is correct that SQL is the way to go. And still I'd like to point out that defining a PLSQL FUNCTION BODY RETURING TEXT style WORKS for LOV definitions. OP's confusion may simply stem from the fact that the official documentation is almost non-existant on this part. Closing it simply because the error message may be evident is a wrong decision here, in my opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a conditional concatenated query:

```
SELECT name display, name return_value
  FROM ns1
 WHERE "type" = :P5_REC_TYPE_ID
   AND :P5_NS_ID IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT name display, name return_value
  FROM ns2
 WHERE "type" = :P5_REC_TYPE_ID
   AND :P5_NS_ID IS NOT NULL
```

Replace `IS NULL`/`IS NOT NULL` with the appropriate logical test.